# How to create a new user correctly in a debian instance?

Tags: openstack, cloud-init, openstack-horizon

I am using ready-made images of debian in the qcow2 format. The default user is "debian". I want to create another user via  openstack-horizon. So I elaborated the following script:

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: jumper
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa myKeyhere
    sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
```

By default, the settings in the /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg file are performed for instance creation. When I create the new user via script the debian user is not created. Is this right? When I create a new user are all cloud.cfg settings ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure that the `default` user is also added by adding `- default` to the lists of users.

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - default
  - name: jumper
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa myKeyhere
    sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
```